# Differentiate $y=(ax+b)^n$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out this problem and have no idea what to do to start this thing out. I know about this power, chain and product rule, but i'm not sure how to apply them here. Also, if someone knows of any good videos that covers this topic, I would greatly appropriate them.

Answer (score 5):

$y' = n(ax+b)^{n-1} \cdot (ax+b)' = n(ax+b)^{n-1} \cdot a$

Comment: Change the typo you have in your post. I almost down voted because I thought you were speaking crazy talk for a second ;)..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot brackets for the superscripts ;)

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $$y=(ax+b)^n$$with respect to $x$ gives us
$$y'=n(ax+b)^{n-1}\cdot (ax+b)'=an(ax+b)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the chain rule to $g(x)=ax+b$ and $f(x)=x^n$, then:

$$(f(g(x)))'=g'(x)f'(g(x))=(ax+b)'f'(ax+b)=af'(ax+b)=an(ax+b)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

by chain rule...
$d(ax + b)^n/dx 
= n(ax + b)^{n-1} \times d(ax + b)/dx
=an(ax + b)^{n-1}$